# Binding via for-loop produces wrong result

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dom-events

I have a number of thumbnails on my website, that are supposed to all bring up the same slide show, but with different slides displayed (by adding and removing a `.hidden` class). This will be done by `function showWork(toShow)`, with `toShow` being a number referring to the slide that is supposed to be visible. The function also alerts back this parameter.

I further want to do this with JavaScript by binding `mouseup` events to the different thumbnail divs.
As I don't want to list every bind separately, I decided to put all the div ids in an array (`workArr`) and create a for-loop:

```
for(i=0; i < workArr.length; i++){
$("#"+workArr[i]).bind({
    mouseup: function(){
        showWork(i);
        }       
});
}
```

My array has a length of 14. When I run this code, I get an alert of "14", and no slide displayed (as there is no 14. slide).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's one mistake every newbie js developer makes !!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use closure:

```
for(i=0; i < workArr.length; i++){
    (function(i){
        $("#"+workArr[i]).bind({
            mouseup: function(){
                showWork(i);
            }       
        });        
    })(i);
}
```